# DISTINCT Statement is not working in Doctrine

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, dql

I try get distinct rows from doctrine, but it not work (uniq hotels)

```
      $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('self');
$qb
    ->distinct('hotel')
    ->join('self.hotel', 'hotel')
    ->where('self.request = :id')
    ->setParameter('id',$requestId);

return $qb->getQuery()->getResult();
```

This DQL returns all hotels.

SQL qwery from Symfony:

[image]

I want this qwery:

```
SELECT  count(DISTINCT hotel_id) FROM symfony.search_result where request_id=@requrst_id
```

Comment: update the question with the SQL query that is generated by the doctrine, and the desired SQL you with to achieve.

Comment: See the update.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your update the DQL you want to build is this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('self');
$qb
->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('hotel.id'))
->join('self.hotel', 'hotel')
->where('self.request = :id')
->setParameter('id',$requestId);

return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();
```

note that i changed the

`->distinct('hotel')`  to `->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('hotel.id'))`

also i changed the

`getResult()`  to  `getSingleScalarResult()`

now  it will return just one result with the count of the unique hotel_ids

Comment: Ok. Search result have a atribute 'hotel', But I  not ndestand how I can't get number hotels:       $templateVars['count']= $hotels; - error. 
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Hotel")
     * @var Hotel
     */
    private $hotel;

Comment: what is the id attribute named in your Hotel entity? Actually you should use the `getScalarResult()` instead of `getSingleResult` so that the query return the number of hotels

Comment: In Hotel entery:   protected $id;

Comment: ok then `->select($qb->expr()->countDistinct('hotel.id'))` is correct

Comment: Ok. Thenks array(1) { [1]=> string(1) "3" }

Comment: did you change the `getSingleResult` to `getSingleScalarResult` ? It should return just the number, not in array

Comment: Yes, I change to    return $qb->getQuery()->getSingleScalarResult();.